# Prime number program Boolean not working properly

Tags: java, loops, boolean

Below is the code for a java programming class I am writing. I cannot figure out why it always prints it is a prime number (true) reguardless of the int I input.  Thank you in advance.  Jared

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeNumbersExample
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int myInt = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    myInt = kb.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime = true;
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < myInt; i++) // exclude 1 and the variable num from the diviso
            if (myInt % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
    }
        if (isPrime=true)
            System.out.println("It is a Prime number.");
        else if (isPrime=false)
            System.out.println("the number is NOT PRIME");
}
```

}

Comment: `if (isPrime=true)`, not `=` should `==` or just `if (isPrime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing the comparison correctly. You just have to say `if(isPrime)` instead of `if(isPrime=true)` because `isPrime` is already a boolean.

```
System.out.println(isPrime ? "Prime" : "Non-Prime");
```

Even if you want to do a comparison you should be using `==` instead of just `=`.

```
if (isPrime == true) {
    System.out.println("It is a Prime number.");
} else {
    System.out.println("the number is NOT PRIME");
}
```

Additionally, you can use a `break` statement inside your `if` to make it stop once the number is identified as Non-Prime.

```
for (int i = 2; i < myInt; i++) {
    if (myInt % i == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int myInt = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    myInt = kb.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < myInt; i++) { // exclude 1 and the variable num from the diviso
            if (myInt % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(isPrime ? "Prime" : "Non-Prime");
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome. If it helped you then request you to accept the answer by clicking the greyed out right click button just below the voting counter.

Answer (score 0):

In the line, if (isPrime=true) what you are going to do is to check whether the isPrime is true, but what the exactly happening is it assign the value true to isPrime and evaluate to true inside the if condition. So what you exactly should do is if (isPrime==true). The corrected code is as follows,

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeNumbersExample
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int myInt = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    myInt = kb.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime = true;
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < myInt; i++) // exclude 1 and the variable num from the diviso
            if (myInt % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
    }
        if (isPrime==true)
            System.out.println("It is a Prime number.");
        else if (isPrime==false)
            System.out.println("the number is NOT PRIME");
}
}
```

*Note - also you can directly use isPrime variable inside the if condition since it is Boolean

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (isPrime=true)` is actually just assigning the value `true` to the `isPrime` variable which will always return true. That's why the first condition is always executed

You can just simply do it like this :

```
if (isPrime) {
    System.out.println("It is a Prime number.");
} else {
    System.out.println("the number is NOT PRIME");
}
```

Also, always put braces for readability

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public class MyPrimeNumCheck {

    public boolean isPrimeNumber(int number){

        for(int i=2; i<=number/2; i++){
            if(number % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        MyPrimeNumCheck mpc = new MyPrimeNumCheck();
        System.out.println("Is 17 prime number? "+mpc.isPrimeNumber(17));
        System.out.println("Is 19 prime number? "+mpc.isPrimeNumber(19));
        System.out.println("Is 15 prime number? "+mpc.isPrimeNumber(15));
    }
}
```